# eas device:create for IOS Simulator

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-eas

Originally asked this question on expo forums but posting it here to widen the net!

https://forums.expo.dev/t/eas-device-create-for-ios-simulator/63417

Answer (score 0):

So you're trying to run the eas development build on an iOS simulator? In my experience it's possible to just add this build profile to your eas.json file and build a new development build based on this build profile.

```
   "development-simulator": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal",
      "android": {
        "gradleCommand": ":app:assembleDebug"
      },
      "ios": {
        "simulator": true,
        "buildConfiguration": "Debug"
      }
    },
```

This file can than be downloaded from your expo.dev dashboard. Unpack the downloaded .tar.gz file and drag the unpacked file into your simulator.